# Unable to suspend in Odin

Tags: suspend, odin

Unable to suspend laptop, it suspends but starts after 5 seconds.
tried from command, when closing lid, and from panel all the same. it starts again by itself.
any help on how to fix it will be appreciated...

Comment: There is not enough information here to offer any suggestions. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the brand and model of your computer (2) whether the machine is using WiFi or a wired network connection? With this it may be possible to identify the problem and offer a solution 

Comment: @matigo thanks for asking what is needed to have a a clear aproach to my Issue. here is the info:
1- Lenovo Legion:
Hexa-Core Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX® 1650 Mobile / Max-Q
2-Unable to suspend in all cases, from wifi either ethernet and wifi and ethernet off,

Comment: I tried this but no success:
https://www.evagabond.me/2020/11/solved-suspend-not-working-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: I also USB booted Manjaro Gnome and same issue. Couldn't suspend, something from my hardware is waking up my OS and can't disable it.

Comment: Lenovo Legion 81SY/LNVNB161216, BIOS BHCN28WW

Comment: Issue solved after elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the update to 6.1 didn't solved the issue.
I could solve it following some help from other topics:

1. Disabling USB devices (including bluetooth) that keeps turning on the device: https://askubuntu.com/a/1144466/603553
2. Suspend On when AC power is connected:
   Following these instructions I've discovered that my device (X1 7th Gen) had a BIOS settings that I can disable/enable suspension when AC power is connected. Also, there is an option to optimize suspension for Linux/Windows OS.

https://superuser.com/questions/1706844/configure-ubuntu-to-unsuspend-when-connected-to-power